# Instantiated prefab is not working as expected but when the prefab is put on the scene then everything runs as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to a prefab and the script is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    Circles circles;

    CircleCollider2D collider1;
    Collider2D collider2;


    private void Start()
    {


        circles = FindObjectOfType<Circles>();

    }
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        collider1 = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        collider2 = gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y < 2)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            circles.instantiator();
            
        }
      



    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
      

        if (collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.max) && collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.min))
       {
            
            if (other.bounds.Contains(collider2.bounds.max) && other.bounds.Contains(collider2.bounds.min))
            {
                
                if (transform.position.y > 3)
                {
                    
                    Destroy(other.gameObject);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    circles.instantiator();
                }

            }

        }
    }





}
```

When I instantiate the prefab the if condition is never running even if the condition is true.
But when I put the prefab on the scene and  play the game then this if condition is running fine according to the condition. I am not able to figure out what is the problem in this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the children of the prefabs in order. The GameObject with the 2D circle collider should be first and the 2nd child should have a 2D collider.

Try:

```
collider1 = GetComponentInChildren<CircleCollider2D>();
collider2 = GetComponentInChildren<Collider2D>();
```

Comment: I have figured out what the problem was. The problem was not with the collider but when the prefabs are instantiated then the z axis bound of the colliders are coming out to be 15.8 because the z axis position of the child was 15.8 and that's why the condition was never met